# XAPK File Validation Failed - APK Expansion Files

Tags: android, apk, apk-expansion-files

I am using the expansion files demo given in the sdks and am placing the obb file on the SD Card at the following location:

```
/Android/obb/package-name/package-name/main.versioncode.package-name.obb
```

But i get the following error:

> XAPK File Validation Failed

---

For generating the `.obb` files this is the procedure i have followed :

1) copy all the images to a folder named `main.versioncode.package-name.obb` and then zip that file.

2) remove .zip file extension and place it in this `/Android/obb/package-name/myobbfile.obb`

Is this the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

An OBB file is an ***uncompressed*** ZIP file, so make sure that you zip it ***without compression***.

Every ZIP utility should have some sort of compression level option.

The following screenshot is the open source [7-ZIP](http://www.7-zip.org/) gui for `Add to Archive` with a highlight i added to show where the `Compression Level` is set to `Store`.

[image]

---

Another way of doing it would be using [`jobb`](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/jobb.html)

> #### Usage
>
> The syntax for running jobb is as follows:
>
> ```
> jobb [-d <directory>][-o <filename>][-pn <package>][-pv <version>] \
>  [-k <key>][-ov][-dump <filename>][-v][-about]
> ```
>
> You can use the jobb tool to create an OBB file or extract the contents of an existing OBB. The following example command creates an OBB file from source files.
>
> ```
> $ jobb -d /temp/assets/ -o my-app-assets.obb -k secret-key -pn com.my.app.package -pv 11
> ```
>
> This example shows how to dump (extract) the contents of an existing OBB file:
>
> ```
> $ jobb -d /temp/obb-output/ -o my-app-assets.obb -k secret-key
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you need to get it done

1) You can put your images in any custom named folder you want. e.g `myimages`.

2) put all those images in a zip archive, once done adding rename that archive to `main.versioncode.package-name.obb`

3) Place that `.obb` file in directory  `sdcar/Android/obb/package-name/main.versioncode.package-name.obb`

Hope it helps